# Turn html form code into single lined embed code

Tags: html

I have spent hours upon hours searching for a solution to this problem. It's probably simple but oh well.

I am coding my very own html forms using html and CSS with a little bit of java script. Before I used online services like Wufoo and form stack. They offered short little embed codes to add to your website page instead of copying the entire form code that is usually 100's of lines long.

I am wanting to make this possible on my forms in order to keep my webpage code clean, clear, and short as possible. Does anyone have a plugin or any ideas of how I could make this work.

Just to be clear I am NOT wanting someone to just provide me code and be on the way. I want suggestions and ideas that could point me in the right direction. Don't over think my question. Once I find a solution to this problem, I will update my question to include the answer for later viewing and help of future visitors.

Comment: these sort of codes would generally be a piece of javascript that contained an ID number to the particular form which would fetch the html from a remote server and then append it to a certain element within the page the javascript code is embedded. you may want to look at something like that

Comment: This question isn't really answerable – yes, you could write some server side code to do this, but if you knew how you wouldn't ask. To write that is not hard, but is more scope than is really available here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read tutorials on w3schools:

http://www.w3schools.com
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

then you will need to process the contents of the forms with a server side language such as php or asp.

Comment: Do not ever link to W3Schools as reference. See why at [W3Fools.com](http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your forms in separate files for example form.htm and then include the file with PHP require("form.htm").